# Pass value from middleware to view in Koa 2

Tags: node.js, koa, koa2

I am trying to get var value from my Koa 2 middleware to display in my pug template (or other).
For example in koa-sessions I have:

```
app.use(ctx => {
  // ignore favicon
  if (ctx.path === '/favicon.ico') return;

  let n = ctx.session.views || 0;
  ctx.session.views = ++n; // how can I use this?
  ctx.body = n + ' views'; // works, but in body directly
  ctx.state.views = n + ' views'; // not working
});
```

Another example, with response time:

```
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  const start = Date.now();
  ctx.state.start = start
  await next();
  const ms = Date.now() - start;
  console.log(`${ctx.method} ${ctx.url} - ${ms}ms`); // this shows response
  ctx.state.ms = await ms>0 // I have no idea what I'm doing :)
});
```

As per original instruction this works, but instead of using body/console, I would like to use it as template variable, so in my router/controller I would have:

```
...
return ctx.render("posts/index", {
  title: 'Posts',
  posts: posts,
  ms: ctx.state.ms,
  views: ctx.session.views // or views: ctx.state.views
});
```

None of this works. Is it related to async/await, so it does not get the value in time or it is some syntactic issue? Please be gentle as I am new in this. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `next()` in your "session" middleware, same way as in the "response time" example.

Like that:

```js
app.use((ctx, next) => {
 let n = ctx.session.views || 0;
  ctx.session.views = ++n;
  next();
});

app.use(ctx => {
  ctx.body = 'Hello ' + ctx.session.views;
  // or you can return rendering result here
});
```

For more info take a look at the [Cascading](http://koajs.com/#cascading) section of their documentation

Comment: Thanks, although my console.log output seems to be somewhat different than the result passed here. Well, I guess it is good enough :)

Comment: There is no console.log in my answer :) Or what do you mean? What you have expected to see and what is the actual output of your console.log?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough - I was using your answer and converting the code for my page speed load var as per second example in the question. console.log(`${ctx.method} ${ctx.url} - ${ms}ms`); produces different results than what I have output on the page.

Comment: I guess that this is because `ms` variable declared after the call to `next()`, this means that you are calculating and printing time after the page was rendered, and that's why they are different.